# How to insert blob data to snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am using snowflake connector to push raw blob data from cerner database to snowflake and I am using the query below.

I am getting the values directly.

```
select blob_contents from ce_blob;
```

While pushing i am using,

```
snowflake_query = "INSERT INTO BLOB_TABLE VALUES (?)"
snowflake_cursor.executemany(snowflake_query , blob)
```

However i am getting the error above which i have posted above.

```
raise error_class(
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 252011: Python data type [lob] cannot be automatically mapped to Snowflake data type. Specify the snowflake data type explicitly.`your text`
```

So i am curious how does anyone store blob data into snowflake? How do i typecast it so i don't have an issue pasting the entire blob.

Also, I do understand that snowflake has Unsupported data type 'BLOB'. So is there a workaround available for it?

I did try to use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(BLOB_CONTENTS)` on the source itself but then it truncates the blob to 2000.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text

Comment: @Narsireddy i am not sure are you typecasting it to some other datatype? If so how are you typecasting before inserting blob to snowflake? Like let us say i need to insert 100k blobs to snowflake how do i go about typecasting each of them in memory?

Comment: Isn't the original data type for blob_contents varbinary? https://docs.healtheintent.com/feed_types/millennium-ods/v1/#ce_blob

Comment: @eww
if i do a desc ce_blob this is what it prints out.
 `Name              Null?    Type         
----------------- -------- ------------ 
EVENT_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER       
UTC_TMP2_2                 DATE         
BLOB_SEQ_NUM      NOT NULL NUMBER       
UTC_TMP2_4                 DATE         
BLOB_LENGTH       NOT NULL NUMBER       
COMPRESSION_CD    NOT NULL NUMBER       
BLOB_CONTENTS              BLOB`